# Share Opengl Es Texture Data between two EGL contexts without making them shared and without using glReadPixels() in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I want to cache video frames coming from media codec with a separate thread and separate egl context  and render with separate thread and separate egl context but I don't want to make them shared and also want to share those cached image textures data.

i have created the egl context using this code

```
public void eglInitPBuffer(int width, int height ,@Nullable EGLConfig config,@Nullable EGLContext sharedContext)
        {
            EGLDisplay dpy = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
            int[] vers = new int[2];
            EGL14.eglInitialize(dpy, vers, 0, vers, 1);


            if (config == null)
            {
                int[] configAttr;

                configAttr = new int[]{
                        EGL14.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE,
                        EGL14.EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
                        EGL14.EGL_LEVEL, 0,
                        EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,
                        EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                        EGL14.EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,
                        EGL14.EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
                        EGL14.EGL_NONE
                };

                EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
                int[] numConfig = new int[1];
                if (!EGL14.eglChooseConfig(dpy, configAttr, 0, configs, 0, configs.length, numConfig, 0)) {
                    Log.e("unable to find RGB8888"," EGLConfig");
                    return;
                }

                config = configs[0];
            }

            int[] surfAttr;
            surfAttr = new int[]{
                    EGL14.EGL_WIDTH, width,
                    EGL14.EGL_HEIGHT, height,
                    EGL14.EGL_NONE
            };

            EGLSurface surf = EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface(dpy, config, surfAttr, 0);;


            checkEglError("eglCreatePbufferSurface");
            if (surf == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("surface was null");
            }

            eglSurface = surf;
            eGLDisplay = dpy;
            configMain = config;

            createEglContext(sharedContext);
        }
```